# How to save the results of a MySQL SELECT query in GoormIDE into a CSV file format

Tags: mysql

I'm working in the DB GoormIDE using MySQL. I run SELECT queries and I'd like to be able to save the resulting table to a CSV file.

I've already tried to add code to the bottom of my original SELECT statement. However I'm not sure what to name the INTO OUTFILE.

```
SELECT * From dogs

INTO OUTFILE '??????????????' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the
>   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement.

I'm actually looking for an easier way to do this without having to add code, similar to how it's done in MySql workbench. It's literally two clicks and you save the search results.

Comment: That would be the filename you'd like the CSV file to be named (which is what you've asked). However, have you actually read the words of the error message? *The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option **so it cannot execute this statement*** seems pretty clear - it's not going to make any difference what you name `OUTFILE` when **it cannot execute this statement** because the server is configured not to allow that statement to be used. IOW, the person who set up the server said **don't let people do this**, and so you can't do it.

Comment: Man that is so lame. Thanks Ken.